# Find point of $n$-sphere after moving on geodesic by given angle

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic, arc-length

Let $\mathbb{S}^n=\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\colon\lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert^2=1\}$ be the unit n-Sphere and $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{S}^n$.

Given a vector $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and an angle $\theta\in[-\pi,\pi)$, we need to find a point $\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{S}^n$ such that it belongs to both the n-Sphere surface and on the geodesic $g_a$, as shown in the figure below.

[image]

**Edit:** I will update the question asap with an answer I came up with after getting help from another question.

Comment: Can you find an expression for $\mathbf{y}$ in the case $n=1$? (Hint. $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{a}/\|\mathbf{a}\|$,form an orthonormal basis.)

Comment: Hi @Kajelad, thanks for your comment. I fixed the questions since I don't really assume perpendicularity on $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{a}$.

Comment: Before, when $a$ was orthogonal to $x$, it could be the derivative of some geodesic through $x$. Now that you removed the orthogonality condition, what is the relation between $a$ and the geodesic $g_a$?

Comment: If $a$ and $x$ are l.i, the the plane through the origin spanned by them intersects the sphere in a great circle which with a certain parametrization will be a geodesic. Now knowing $\theta$ you can find $y$, if e.g., you use the arclength parametrization, $y=g_a(\theta)$.

Comment: Hi @Laz, thanks for coming back to this question as well! Truth is that I'm still trying to formalize the problem for my needs (for a Machine Learning application). So, I am not sure that I do not need the orthogonality condition (I'd like to check without it first).

Comment: Perhaps you've already figured this out, but you are taking the projection $\mathbf a^{\|}$ of $\mathbf a$ onto the tangent plane (i.e., subtracting off the component parallel to $\mathbf x$) and taking the geodesic in that direction. Yes, the $2$-dimensional plane spanned by $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf a$ is the same as the $2$-dimensional plane spanned by $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf a^{\|}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin many thanks for your comment! First, you mean that $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{a}$ span the $n$-dimensional hyperplane, right? Also, for a given vector in the the tangent space, how is the geodesic defined? Shouldn't we find a parameterization that would benefit traveling across it by given angle (e.g., the given $\theta$)? Anyway, may thanks for the taking the time.

Comment: No, not hyperplane. Two linearly independent vectors span a $2$-plane. If you project, as I said, you can write down an easy parametrization of the great circle.

Comment: @TedShifrin If I understand it correctly, the tangent space at $\mathbf{x}$ is defined by the perpendicular  $\mathbf{x}$ and thus the projection of $\mathbf{a}$ is: $\mathbf{a}^\parallel=\mathbf{a}-\frac{\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{x}}{\lVert\mathbf{a}\rVert^2}\cdot\mathbf{x}$. Then, $\mathbf{x}$ and $\frac{\mathbf{a}^\parallel}{\lVert\mathbf{a}^\parallel\rVert}$ form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which I can use to define the geodesic? Did I understand it? Thank you very much!